# How can I create a priority queue of pairs that's sorted by the first element and then by the second?

Tags: c++, queue

I created a lambda comp according to what I use in vectors, but it doesn't work, I would like to know why it doesn't work and how to do it properly.

CODE:

```
auto cmp=[](const std::pair<int,int>& a,const std::pair<int,int>& b){
    return (b.first>a.first)||(b.second>a.second);
};
std::priority_queue<std::pair<int,int>,std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>,decltype(cmp)> q(cmp);
```

Comment: Isn't that how [the standard `std::pair` comparison operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) already work?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the comparison operator works a.first>b.first I think, how can I change that?

Comment: `b > a` is the same as `a <= b`. Think about that for a moment.

Comment: well, I ended up using `std::greater<std::pair<int,int>>` and it works, but what if I wanted to sort increasinly by the first then decreasingly by the second, how would I do that?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "then" (and I'm not being a smartass; understanding strict weak ordering is important when you're using ordered containers in the standard library). `a.first > b.first || (!(b.first > a.first) && a.second < b.second)` *may* be what you're after, but hard to say.

Comment: @WhozCraig you're right. I was sloppy with the strict weak ordering. Ty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments: `std::greater<std::pair<int, int>>` works just fine, and yours not working because the comparison equation isn't 'strict enough' - right.

Lets take two pairs p1 = (3,5) and p2 = (4,2), if we comapre p1 and p2 according to your function, it will output `cmp(p1, p2) = true` because of `b.first > a.first // 4 > 3`.

Also, if we compare p2 and p1 the same way(the only difference is the order of p1 and p2), it will output `cmp(p2, p1) = true` because of `b.second > a.second // 5 > 2`.

Not saying anything, when `a == b`, if we compare some pair to itself it will be `false`.

So the compiler has to have problems while comparing the same pairs one more time, but this time with the reverse order.

Since the question doesn't contain many details about how you use the queue, the problem has to be this. That's why `greater` working and not this one.
If you want to make work yours, you should try a more specific and strict equation, try to use the `&&` operator instead of `||` and consider the equal variant too.

Hope it helps, I had similar problems a few years ago, while I was trying to sort vector of pairs by my way.